# Using Jest to mock named imports

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, es6-modules

I have a 'notifications.js' module that looks a bit like this:

```js
import { Notifications, Permissions } from 'expo'

export function setLocalNotification(storage = AsyncStorage) {
  return storage
    .getItem(NOTIFICATION_KEY)
    .then(JSON.parse)
    .then(data => {
      if (data === null) {
        return Permissions.askAsync(
          Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
        ).then(({ status }) => {
          if (status === 'granted') {
            Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync()
            ...etc.
```

In my test, I want to mock Permissions and Notifications so I can do something like this in notifications.spec.js:

```js
import { setLocalNotification } from './notifications'
import mockAsyncStorage from '../mock/AsyncStorage'

it('correctly cancels pending notifications', done => {
  setLocalNotification(mockAsyncStorage).then(done())
  expect(Permissions.askAsync).toBeCalled()
  expect(Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync)
    .toBeCalled()
})
```

I've tried various things using `jest.mock` and `jest.setMock` but I can't seem to get this working. How do I go about mocking these named imports in the desired way? For instance, I've tried this:

```js
jest.setMock('Permissions', () => ({
  askAsync: jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ status: 'granted' }))
}))
```

But that doesn't work. It throws

```
'module Permissions cannot be found from notifications.spec.js'
```

And if I try to mock the entire expo module, the mocked functions `expect().toBeCalled()` returns false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to mock the module `'expo'`

```
jest.mock('expo', ()=>({
  Permissions: {
     askAsync: jest.fn()
  }
}))
```

Comment: I had initially tried this, but I thought it wasn't working because my tests were failing. But it turned out they were failing because my implementation had a bug. So this is indeed the correct approach.

Comment: this is the answer that works for me, to a question I've searched for many times without success in the past