# Jest Mocking Permissions of Expo TypeError: Cannot read property 'askAsync' of undefined

Tags: permissions, mocking, jestjs, expo

I'm mocking expo and the Permissions module, but when calling Permissions.AskAsync Permissions is undefined.

Problem looks like this question. [Using Jest to mock named imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761107/using-jest-to-mock-named-imports/46765011#46765011)

Used the provided answer, but did not work.

I have mocked the axios, which works. Doing the same for the expo module does not work.

The function I want to test:

```
    checkPermission = async () => {


        const {statusCamera} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);

        // console.log(statusCamera);

        this.setState({cameraPermission: statusCamera});

        const {statusCameraRoll} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        this.setState({cameraRollPermission: statusCameraRoll});
    };
```

The test:

```
describe("Test the Permission function", () => {
    it('should return rejected permission.', async function () {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Photo2/>);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();

        await instance.checkPermission();

        expect(instance.state("cameraPermission")).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

The mock I use for expo:

```
jest.mock('expo', ()=>({
  Permissions: {
     askAsync: jest.fn()
  }
}))
```

and tried 
(In file **mocks**/expo.js)

```
export default {
    Permissions: {
        askAsync: jest.fn(() => {
            return "SOMETHING"
        })

    }
}
```

and tried 
(In file **mocks**/expo.js)

```
jest.mock('expo', ()=>({
    Permissions: {
        askAsync: jest.fn()
    }
}));
```

> Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'askAsync' of undefined"

This error occures on line where `Permissions.askAsyc` is called. So Permissions is undefined. (Also checked it with `console.log(Permissions)`

I expected the `instance.state("cameraPermission")` to be falsy, but it crashes before it comes to that line.

Answer (score 1):

Since expo change the packages to be `import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';`

You just need to create "mocks/expo-permissions.js" and have it has:

```js
export const getAsync = jest.fn(permissions => Promise.resolve());
export const askAsync = jest.fn(permissions => Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 1):

[teerryn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465070/3267272) is correct and is a good start. To add some more details:

1. Unless you've configured different `roots` for Jest, you should place your mock file in `__mocks__/expo-permissions.js` where `__mocks__` is a directory at the same level as your `node_modules` folder. See Jest docs on [mocking node modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules).
2. The `permissions` argument being passed in will be undefined due to the way we're mocking the module, so you'll need to mock the permission types you want to use. Just need something simple like `export const CAMERA_ROLL = 'camera_roll';`
3. If you want to respond differently based on the permission type passed in (for example, allow `Permissions.CAMERA` but deny `Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL` and all other types), you can mock the implementation of the `askAsync` function. For example, your `__mocks__/expo-permissions.js` file would look like this:

```js
export const CAMERA = 'camera';
export const CAMERA_ROLL = 'camera_roll';
export const askAsync = jest.fn().mockImplementation((permissionType) => {
  const responseData = permissionType === CAMERA ? { status: 'granted' } : { status: 'undetermined' }; // you could also pass `denied` instead of `undetermined`
  return Promise.resolve(responseData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are handling async tests incorrectly (your `checkPermission()` function is async). There are several ways you can tell jest that you want to test an async function. [Here are a few ways.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html)

Here is a quick solution to your problem:

```js
...

import { Permissions } from 'expo';

...

jest.mock('expo', () => ({
    Permissions: {
        askAsync: jest.fn(),
    }
}));

...

describe("Test the Permission function", () => {
    it('should return rejected permission.', () => {
        Permissions.askAsync.mockImplementation( permission => { return {status: 'granted'}; } ); // if you want to add some sort of custom functionality

        const wrapper = shallow(<Photo2/>);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();

        return instance.checkPermission().then(data => {
            expect(instance.state("cameraPermission")).toBeFalsy();
        });
    });
});
```