# Jest - how to detect if a named export in a module dependancy is called?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

// dependancy.js

```
export const getFontSize = () => {
    // expensive computation...
};
```

// device.js

```
import { getFontSize } from './dependancy';
...
const initPxToEm = () => {
    let fontSize;
    return px => {
        if (!fontSize) {
            fontSize = getFontSize();
        }
        return stripUnit(em(px, fontSize));
    };
};
const pxToEm = initPxToEm();
const doSomething = () => pxToEm(window.innerWidth);
```

I want to test that getFontSize is only called once, i.e. the function is memoized:

// test.js

```
import device from '../device';
import { getFontSize } from '../dependancy';
jest.mock('../dependancy');

it('should memoize the font size', () => {
    device.doSomething();
    expect(getFontSize).toHaveBeenCalled();
    device.doSomething();
    expect(getFontSize).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but I get this:

> Expected mock function not to be called but it was called with:
> [], []

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761107/using-jest-to-mock-named-imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(number)](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber) to check the `getFontSize` function is called only once.  Besides, you forgot to mock a return value for `getFontSize` function, This will cause your `fontSize` variable to never have a true value(`undefined`). So every time call `device.doSomething()` method will call the `getFontSize` function is called.

E.g.

`dependancy.js`

```js
export const getFontSize = () => {
  // expensive computation...
};
```

`device.js`:

```js
import { getFontSize } from './dependancy';

const stripUnit = (val) => val;
const em = (px, fontSize) => px + fontSize;

const initPxToEm = () => {
  let fontSize;
  return (px) => {
    if (!fontSize) {
      fontSize = getFontSize();
    }
    return stripUnit(em(px, fontSize));
  };
};
const pxToEm = initPxToEm();
const doSomething = () => pxToEm(window.innerWidth);

export default { doSomething };
```

`device.test.js`:

```js
import device from './device';
import { getFontSize } from './dependancy';

jest.mock('./dependancy');

it('should memoize the font size', () => {
  getFontSize.mockReturnValue(16);
  device.doSomething();
  device.doSomething();
  device.doSomething();
  expect(getFontSize).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66557208/device.test.js
  ✓ should memoize the font size (3 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |   83.33 |     100 |                   
 dependancy.js |     100 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 device.js     |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.665 s, estimated 4 s
```